# No legend visible in a ggplot set of code although it should be

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have run the following code :`

```
g <- ggplot(results_table, aes(x = "", y = Pct*100, fill = Criteria),width = 1) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = Palcolor, fill = Palcolor) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(),, 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)) + 
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(0.3, "lines"), #smaller squares
    legend.key.width = unit(0.7, "lines"), #smaller squares
    legend.margin=margin(l = 40, unit='pt'),
    legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(r = 60,  unit = "pt"))) +
  xlab("") +  
  ylab("") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.70, y = Pct*100/2 + c(0, cumsum(Pct*100)[-length(Pct*100)]),
                label = paste0(sprintf("%0.1f", round(Pct*100, digits = 1)),"%")),
            size = 3.2) +
  labs(title = gTitle)
```

}`

It created the pie chart as expected, but not the customized legend :

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Please provide the data you used to generate the plot such that others can reproduce it. Have a look at the documentation of the `dput()` to learn how. Alternatively, use a built in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the custom color and fill palettes as arguments inside `geom_bar`. This way no legend will show up. You have to use `scale_color/fill_manual` to set the color palettes for the `color/fill` aesthetics.

Using `ggplot2::mpg` as example data and an example palette from `RColorBrewer` try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example data
results_table <- mpg %>% 
  count(class) %>% 
  mutate(Pct = n / sum(n),
         class = reorder(class, Pct)) %>% 
  rename(Criteria = class) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Pct)) %>% 
  mutate()
# Example palette as named vector to get the colors and categories right
Palcolor <- c("2seater" = "#8DD3C7", "minivan" = "#FFFFB3", "pickup" = "#BEBADA", "subcompact" = "#FB8072", "midsize" = "#80B1D3", "compact" = "#FDB462", "suv" = "#B3DE69")
# Example title
gTitle = "Example title"

g <- ggplot(results_table, aes(x = "", y = Pct*100, fill = Criteria),width = 1) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values = Palcolor) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Palcolor) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(),, 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)) + 
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(0.3, "lines"), #smaller squares
    legend.key.width = unit(0.7, "lines"), #smaller squares
    legend.margin=margin(l = 40, unit='pt'),
    legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(r = 60,  unit = "pt"))) +
  xlab("") +  
  ylab("") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.70, y = Pct*100/2 + c(0, cumsum(Pct*100)[-length(Pct*100)]),
                label = paste0(sprintf("%0.1f", round(Pct*100, digits = 1)),"%")),
            size = 3.2) +
  labs(title = gTitle)
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The legend is visible now. Nevertheless, the percentages around the pie, the colors and the slices are muddled. I'm going to create a new question to show this new issue.

Comment: Hi @JacquesTroussart. That's the problem when you don't put your data into your post. The point is that ggplot will by default reorder your categories alpahebtically. This way the colors and labels get muddled. To get the colors right, you have use a named color palette (see my edit). To get the labels right is more tricky. To get your solution work I did two things. First I reordered the categories according to Pct (see the line `class = reorder(class, Pct)`. Second I had to reorder the dataset by Pct in descending order. That's what I did with `arrange(desc(Pct))`.

Comment: Still thanks for your reply. Fiirst for your info, the data frame results_data is already ordered decreasingly by Pct In the meantime I have found an other solution, I replace "fill = Criteria" by "fill = factor(r.esults_table$Criteria, as.character(results_table$Criteria))" and it is better. the only remaining issue is that the percentages are in clockwise order and the slide (and colors) are in anticlockwise order.